# Import into Aperture 3 without moving files

Tags: macos, photos, aperture, picture-import-wizard

I like managing my own files, and this is definitely possible with Aperture 3. But there seems to be two ways to import into Aperture: either by dragging and dropping, or importing one folder at a time, manually, through the Aperture import window.

BUT whenever I drag and drop the photos, it imports them into the Aperture library, making duplicates of everything. And if I add them manually through Aperture, I have to add each folder at a time, which is extremely tedious.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you want them in the Aperture Library? I believe that you have the option under Import Settings.

Comment: @ioi: the only relevant option is "Default import location" and the options are "New Project" or "Selected item". Both options seem to relocate the file.

Comment: I'll post a screenshot.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same problem and have been able to solve it using the automator. I added a screenshot of the automator workflow I created. I use it to import a lot of directories into one project at a time without copying them into the Aperture library.

Please note, that there's a bug. After saving and reopening the workflow, the "Import nach Reference" (import by reference) check box is no longer checked. Actually this is the esential setting preventing you files beeing copyied to the library.

If there's a possibility to export this workflow, I'm happy to post it. Feal free to guide a automator novice.

[image: Aperture Import with Automator]

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop a file into Aperture holding cmd+option and it will add it to your library as an externally referenced file (as opposed to copying the file itself into the library). You'll know you are doing it correctly because the cursor icon will change to a little curved arrow, as indicated in this screenshot: https://cloudup.com/cPQFpDZi75g

Answer (score 0):

You can choose how Aperture Imports files/folders by changing the Import Settings, so you don't have to have them in the Aperture Library necessarily; try using current location, or choose another folder :

[image: Aperture Import Settings]

Comment: Yes, but this exactly my problem. I don't want to use Aperture's import tool because that means I have to select each subfolder individually, which takes forever. I'd rather drag the parent folder into the Aperture window and have it autoimport.